# SQL Login failing on SQL Server 2008 for Remote Connections

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-connection, sqlconnection

This snippet of C# code is used to connect to a SQL Server 2008 instance (default, not named instance):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnType))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand query = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        query.CommandText = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["query"].ToString();
        using (SqlDataReader dataReader = query.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dataReader.HasRows && dataReader.Read())
            {
                // do something with the result
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Based on command line arguments, `sqlConnType` (parameter used to instantiate a SqlConnection object) is one of the following:

Integrated Windows Authentication: `Data Source=<ServerName>;database=<DatabaseName>;Integrated Security=True`

SQL Authentication: `server=<ServerName>;database=<DatabaseName>;user id=<UserID>;pwd=<Password>`

I have added firewall rule to allow for SQL traffic. Named pipes and TCP/IP are enabled. Both Windows and SQL Server Authentication is also enabled. Now the strange part...

When an application using the above code connects remotely to the SQL Server using Int. Windows Authentication, the connection works just fine. However, when I try to connect remotely using SQL Server Authentication, I get the error: `Cannot open database "<DatabaseName>" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user '<UserID>'.` If I print the stack trace of the exception, I get something like this:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at App.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\App\Program.cs:line 31
```

**Note**: If I run the application **locally** on the SQL Server, Int. Windows authentication works but not SQL Login Authentication again. The same application can talk to older versions of SQL Server (e.g. 2005) using the same code, in both authentication modes, and same connection strings just fine.

What am I doing wrong? Is it something specific to SQL Server 2008 I am missing?

Comment: Can you login with the SQL Authentication credentials locally?

Comment: I thought I could... now looks like that is not working either.

Comment: Figure that out and you'll likely have a solution.  As far as the Domain Auth, is your app running under that credential?

Comment: Yes, for the domain auth, the app is running under that credential. Both remotely as well as locally, if I access SQL Server using SQL Management Studio, I can access it just fine with SQL Server authentication and specifying the SQL Login's credentials. Only through code, I am unable to, as if there is a problem with my connection string. Is there a SQL Server 2008 specific connection string for SQL Server logins? I checked connectionstrings.com and tried a few... did not help.

Comment: Yes, the app works just fine with SQL Auth, both remotely and locally.

Comment: Standalone or web app?

Comment: Standalone console app.

Comment: Can you find the corresponding error in the Windows Event log and post it?

Comment: There is nothing in the EventViewer (both on the SQL 2008 Server as well as the Client machine) corresponding to this error.

Comment: `Login failed for user 'UserID'`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who looked at this and provided feedback! It turned out to be a false alarm, because I was looking at the wrong server. Few months ago, I had set up a newer server and migrated all the databases to over there. And I set up SQL aliases using the old server hostname to route to the new server. I forgot about it and persevered with trying to solve the problem on the old server. The whole time, it was the new server that was configured only for Windows Auth and I just had to change it to Mixed Mode Auth. That fixed the issue.

I did come across some insightful links, when you run into connectivity issues:

[Troubleshoot Connectivity/Login Failures SQL Server 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsakthi/archive/2011/02/06/how-to-troubleshoot-connectivity-failure-error-with-sql-server.aspx)